# Is it possible to schedule an AMPScript in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I somehow gets some same weird records created in DE like below :

[image]

They have different ids but same `phone(46)`, opt dates (`1/1/1900`) and same empty values for other fields as in image. I don't have time to troubleshoot the problem so I want to schedule (wonder if it can be done via automation studio ) an AMPScript delete script (a landing page containing the script) on the DE...

Is it doable? Any pointers?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you explain a little further what you are trying to do? Your issue may be solvable using a query activity.

Comment: Above some more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a staging DE.
2. Write a query activity to query the existing DE into that staging DE.  Make sure overwrite is selected.
3. Write another query activity that copies the entirety of the staging table over the existing DE.  Again select overwrite.
4. Put steps 2&3 in a program or an automation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should help. I will give a try sooner i get some time.